# This page doesn’t appear to be using React. If this seems wrong, follow the troubleshooting instructions on Microsoft Edge

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-edge, react-devtools

I created the build of a `MERN Stack` application using the `npm run build` command, then I ran this built application on my default browser (Microsoft Edge) using the `npm start` command. I then installed the `react devtools` extension for `Edge` from `Chrome`. But when I enable `react devtools` on my react app, it does not activate and I get the message **This page doesn’t appear to be using React.
If this seems wrong, follow the troubleshooting instructions.** I don't understand why I get this error because my application is entirely designed in react on the frontend side. I don't know if it's because I got the wrong server start command .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following solution.
In Edge, right click on React devtools, go to Manage extensions, and select "Allow access to file URLs".
[image]
Also, it has been reported that a re-installation of react devtools and a restart of browser may help. By the way, react devtools is available in [Microsoft Edge Add-ons](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/react-developer-tools/gpphkfbcpidddadnkolkpfckpihlkkil), so you can just install it in Edge (since you said you installed it from Chrome).

Comment: It also works in Chrome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Chrome to last version worked for me.

```
Chrome version: 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
System version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```